Troubleshooting Tabulator pagination with Laravel
I am working with Tabulator pagination. Here is my Tabulator code and Laravel function:
var lastPage = parseInt($('#dataTable').data('last-page'));
var initialPage = 1;
if (lastPage >= 2) {
    initialPage = 2;
}
var table = new Tabulator("#dataTable", {
    // columns configuration...
    layout: "fitColumns",
    pagination: true, //enable pagination
    paginationMode: "remote", //enable remote pagination
    ajaxURL: "{{ route('listorders') }}", //set url for ajax request
    paginationSize: 10,
    paginationInitialPage: initialPage,
    paginationDataReceived: {
        last_page: "last_page"
    },
});

Here is the Laravel function:
public function listorders(Request $request)
{
    // Check if the request is AJAX
    if ($request->ajax()) {
        $perPage = $request->input('size', 10); 

        $orders = Order::with(['hospital_detail', 'items', 'doctor_detail', 'shipment' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('shipment_status', '!=', 'cancelled');
        }])
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
            ->paginate($perPage);

        return response()->json(['last_page' => $orders->lastPage(), 'data' => $orders->items()]);
    } else {
        $perPage = $request->input('size', 10);
        $initialOrders  = Order::with(['hospital_detail', 'items', 'doctor_detail', 'shipment' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('shipment_status', '!=', 'cancelled');
        }])
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
            ->paginate($perPage);

        $response=[
            'orders' => $initialOrders,
            'last_page' => $initialOrders->lastPage()
        ];

        return view('orders.list',$response );
    }
}

I am handling both requests. The else condition is specifically for initiating the Laravel view. The main problem is that the initial page does not show the maximum number of pages. It only shows 1 page.
I have tried the last_page params to send the payload to the view page, but it's also not working. Although it shows the correct 13 pages in my response, it's also not working with pagination.

Thankyou everyone! i solved this thing by making an additional AJAX request on page load and it fixed this problem.
